# Неправильная группировка

Tags: java

Всем Привет помогите пожалуйста с исправлением кода, есть вот такой код:

```
class C {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String rows[] = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next().split("\n");  

for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
   rows[i] = rows[i].trim();

       System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------");

        List<String> newLines = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder newLine = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line : rows) {
            if (line.endsWith("{")) {
                if (newLine.length() > 0) {
                    newLines.add(newLine.toString());
                }
                 newLine = new StringBuilder(line);
            } else {
            newLine.append("\n").append(line);      
            }

        }
        newLines.add(newLine.toString());
    }
}
```

программа должна читать из файла где находится некий код в текстовом виде, и производить группировку отдельно If While for от , но вот что она выводит на экран

(1 вариант)

```
0)'Class A{'
1)'if(a==0){
System.out.println(a);
}'
2)'if(a==0){
System.out.println(a);
}
}'
```

а мне нужно чтоб 2 элемент группировался вот так, до своей закрывающийся скобки

(2 вариант)

```
 0)'Class A{
    1)'if(a==0){
    System.out.println(a);
    }
    '
    2)'if(a==0){
    System.out.println(a);
    }'

    }'
```

Я не понимаю, где ошибка, и почему результат этого кода как 1 вариант хотя я ожидал 2 вариант

Comment: У вас вывод не соответствует коду. Да и в целом проблема описана так, что вообще ничего не понятно.

Comment: Группировать можно с помощью стека.